# Kotlin callbackFlow awaitClose trigger problem when delay

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I couldn't understand something about `callbackFlow`. I have two implementation. There is only difference both of them is using `delay` or any other suspend function which includes `delay`. When I run 1. implementation, `awaitClose` block doesn't run but there is no problem when run the 2. implementation. Coroutine was canceled when I call the `first` function and in my code implementation needs `first` call.

I believe there is a logical explanation about that but I couldn't solve it.

##### 1. Implementation

```
val callbackFlow = callbackFlow {
    send("Value")
    delay(100)
    awaitClose { println("Channel was closed") }
}

val firstValue = callbackFlow.first()
println(firstValue)
```

##### 2. Implementation

```
val callbackFlow = callbackFlow {
    send("Value")
    awaitClose { println("Channel was closed") }
}

val firstValue = callbackFlow.first()
println(firstValue)
```

Comment: The existing answer summarizes the problem pretty well. That said, why use `callbackFlow` here at all? This is not the intended use of `callbackFlow`. The point of this type of flow is to feed it with elements from a separate coroutine or callback, and thus the necessity of `awaitClose()` to keep the flow going while such coroutines produce elements and collectors are still interested in them. If you don't use callbacks or launch coroutines, just use `flow { .. }`

Comment: @Joffrey this implementation is only represent my situation. It doesn't related with `flow`.

Comment: Still, even if you simplify for the sake of the example, not launching coroutines is a crucial difference. So either your real life code is close to your question and suffers from the same issue, or your real life code is fundamentally different and the question should be edited to better reflect why your code needs `callbackFlow`. Otherwise the answer to your question is just "don't use callback flow like this" - which is likely not what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flow.first()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/first.html) **cancels** the flow once the first value has been collected.

In your case, it means that the `awaitClose` function is never reached.

1. The call to `callbackFlow.first()` triggers flow collection
2. The `send("value")` transmit value to the collector
3. The collector cancels the flow
4. Then, depending on your implementation

   1. The delay might have start, and is cancelled along the flow. The "awaitClose" function is never reached.
   2. Without delay, there's a chance that 'awaitClose' might register the lambda (and therefore execute it) faster than the collector cancels the flow.

Note however, I'm not sure that the `awaitClose` is always reachable, even without delay. More research would be needed to give a definitive answer for that.

Comment: Thank you @amanin. I think, you clearly explain situation. When I check documentation, the problem is related with cancelation and `first` call. I never thought about the `awaitClose` is reachable but now it is more brighten in my mind.